# What process on my jail broken iPhone is listening on port 80

Tags: ios, iphone

I can access it via telnet from the internet once I get the IP of my phone
Probably an HTTP server

```
telnet  XXXX 80
Trying XXXX...
Connected to XXXX.
Escape character is '^]'.
HELP
<HEAD><TITLE>Invalid HTTP Request</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Invalid HTTP Request</H1><HR>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Bad request syntax</B></FONT>
<HR>
<!-- default "Invalid HTTP Request" response (400) -->
</BODY>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

It's a jailbroken device

Is there a way to find out which process is listening on this port?

Comment: Hi Shai, welcome to [security.se]. Please read [ask] and take a look at the [FAQ] - this question is not really a security question per se, its more about how to configure your iPhone (so you might have better luck at [apple.se]). Besides that, I dont think there is really enough information to properly answer this - can you add some more context?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want to run "netstat" on your jail-broken device

http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/971616

Related:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12238/how-to-display-alter-a-jailbroken-ios-devices-route-table

This looks interesting... No idea if it works:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/netstat/id400071873?mt=8